# What should I say in response to "I hope next year is better"?

Tags: politeness, responses

How should I reply to this statement without using a bland "me too"? I want the conversation to keep going past this, but I'm not sure how to respond well.

Comment: You could tempt the Kindly Ones by saying "well, it couldn't get much worse!" On a more practical note, you could pick out one positive thing that you wish for in the new year "Yes, let's hope this vaccine works!" or "Yes, let's hope we can all get back to work again".

Answer (score 1):

Here are the options that I can think of:

<sup>I will call the other person Bob.</sup>

#### To reply hoping the Covid-19 pandemic will be better:

**Option 1:**

> Bob: "I hope next year is better"
> You: "Yeah let's hope we can travel again this year!"

^ above is hoping that we can start traveling again next year.

**Option 2:**

> Bob: "I hope next year is better"
> You: "Yeah let's hope the vaccine works!"

^ above is hoping that the vaccine will works and help fading the pandemic.

**Option 3:**

> Bob: "I hope next year is better"
> You: "Yeah let's hope we can all get back to work again!"

^ above is hoping that we can all get out of the lock down and start working again.

**Option 4:**

> Bob: "I hope next year is better"
> You: "Yeah let's hope the pandemic will end!"

^ the above is just hoping that the whole pandemic will end.

#### To reply hoping the whole year would be better:

**Option 1:**

> Bob: "I hope next year is better"
> You: "I don't think it could be any worse than this year"

^ above is just mentioning that the next year can't be any worse than this year.

**Option 2:**

> Bob: "I hope next year is better"
> You: "Yeah hope next year will be a complete turnaround of this year!"

^ above is hoping that the next year would be completely different and better than this year.

**Option 3:**

> Bob: "I hope next year is better"
> You: "We gotta make the next year a good year!"

^ above is saying that we need to make the next year a really good year.

**Option 4:**

> Bob: "I hope next year is better"
> You: "Yes! We can do it this year!"

^ above is saying that we can do it this year, make it meaning that we will make this year good.

---

There are my suggestions of replying to that sentence.